# Gazier, synonyme de quidam en argot, est-il toujours utilisé?

Tags: argot

J'ai découvert aujourd'hui que le mot *gazier* est un synonyme argotique de *quidam*<sup>[(1)](http://www.crisco.unicaen.fr/cgi-bin/trouvebis2?requete=gazier#classement) [(1A)](http://www.crisco.unicaen.fr/des/synonymes/gazier) [(2)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/gazier)</sup>.

Je ne lui connaissais pas cet emploi. Sait-on quand il est apparu, et s'il est toujours utilisé ? Est-ce un régionalisme ?

Comment: Bonjour à tous, Je confirme l'utilisation du coté de Toulouse, et je suis justement curieux de savoir d'où cette expression provient.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Je ne connaissais pas le mot dans ce sens là.  Le *dictionnaire du français non conventionnel*  (Jacques Cellard et Alain Rey - 1980) fait apparaître le mot avec ce sens en 1945.
Et donne deux origines possibles :

> Apparu dans les casernes, le mot a pu tirer son origine de [paronymies](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paronymie) convergentes :
>
> celle de *gars* et de *gaz* (*les gars* −> *les gaz*), renforcée par l'emploi commun de « Compagnie » (la 4e Compagnie −> la *Compagnie du Gaz*) ;
>
> celle de *gazer* (aller vite), dont [Esnault](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaston_Esnault)  fait dériver le mot est moins convaincante ; le *gazier* n'est pas « un homme qui gaze, qui va vite et bien », mais au contraire un personnage très quelconque.
>
> En 1952 dans l'armée le mot était nettement senti comme rattaché à *Gaz* ; dans la vie civile, *l'employé* (de la Compagnie) *du gaz* chargé de relever les compteurs ou d'encaisser les quittances, est le visiteur « quelconque » et anonyme par excellence.

Et le tout accompagné d'une citation extraite de [L'hercule sur la place](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Hercule_sur_la_place) de Bernard Clavel, écrit en 1966.

Comment: Je me suis demandée aussi si on ne pourrait pas (en se tirant bien les cheveux tout de même), relier *gazier* /gazje/ à l'anglais *geezer* /giːzə(r)/ défini ainsi dans l'OED  :
*A term of derision applied esp. to men, usu. but not necessarily elderly; a chap, fellow.*
                                                           Phonétiquement le passage de *geezer* à *gazier* ne me semble pas tout à fait impossible.

Answer (score 10):

Je ne sais pas si c'est un régionalisme mais il m'arrive de l'entendre ici à Toulouse. Ça reste rare mais tout à fait compris.

Les expressions les plus courantes sont *Salut les gaziers!* lancée à la cantonade à un cercle d'amis, ou bien *C'est qui ce gazier?* à propos d'un tiers qui n'a pas ses habitudes à l'endroit où les interlocuteurs se trouvent.

Ça ne m'étonnerais pas que le mot survive grâce à San Antonio.

Answer (score 2):

Il est assez répandu dans l'armée.

Answer (score 1):

À Marseille on l'utilise tous les jours !

> Putain, con c'est qui le gazier là ? Mdr

Donc *gazier* s'utilise pour dire *mec, zigue, zèbre, type, bonhomme...* Bref, un individu quelconque.

Answer (score 1):

On l'utilise couramment à Brest dans la classe populaire. On l'emploie pour dire : le gars, le type ou bien le mec.

Answer (score 0):

Chez nous dans la Loire (42) on employait le terme "gazier" pour dire de quelqu'un que c'était un drôle de type, plutôt péjoratif :)

Answer (score 0):

Dans  le sud c’est quelqu’un qui boit comme un trou

Comment: Bienvenue, pourriez-vous nous communiquer des références ?

Answer (score 0):

Oui, ce type, ce pékin, ce quidam, ce pignouf(pej) ...!
Mais "ce gars" au singulier se termine par S ! (non prononcé, sauf par Chirac) 
Alors pourquoi pas, un suffixe, une déclinaison marrante ou une déviance argotique : ce gasse, ce gassier, ce gasier, ce gazier ?